# SP2-0640: Not connected on sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am new user for sqldeveloper and I try to create a new user.

I use this command line: `create user <myusernanme> identify by <password>`

But I get this error: `SP2-0640: Not connected`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: _"I am new user for sqldeveloper"_    But your subject line references sqlplus.  So which of those two client programs are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you connected to a database?
Check:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a90842/qstart.htm
connect username/password@connect_identifier

Answer (score 1):

Thank you ! I discovered there that to create a new user I must be logged in.
I connected the SYS ultilistator with the command

```
CONNECT SYS AS SYSDBA
```

Create my user with the command

```
CREATE USER <username> IDENTIFIED BY <password>
```

and finally I give him the authorization to create his own session

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO <username>;
```

But how do I disconnect the SYS user?

Comment: disconnect should work, or you can just close the sqlplus
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12020.htm

Comment: Indeed, its works. Thank!

Comment: My favourite SQL\*Plus command: `disco`